# Only Deploy Changed Files Using Jenkins and Git

Tags: deployment, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm deploying a PHP app, Drupal to be exact and I've decided to use Jenkins for CI. I have it deploying fine using the Publish Over SSH but it deploys the entire site every time which is obviously quite slow. I know there are tools like Ant, Maven, Phing and Capistrano but I want to know which is my best option?

I'm currently just working on deployments but here is an overview of my final goal.

1. Checkout source code. (Using the Git plugin which works fine.)
2. Build SASS or LESS files
3. Run Drupal tests using drush
4. Deploy code. Only deploying the code files that have changed.

I would appreciate recommendations of the best tools to use from here based on your experiences configuring something similar to above.

Comment: Have the same problem, I don't know exactly what the difference between jenkins and for example ant. :S I'm not sure it would be a wise thing to deploy only the changes with git. In that case you have to separate your project from your wwwroot, so you can put a temporarily unavailable label while the repo is changing. The entire history will be saved to the server, so you have to pay attention to the large files. It's very hard to clear them from the history after you don't need them especially when you are working in team. Maybe rsync would be a better solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just deploying code then it shouldn't be slow. I'm guessing you have something bad like assets in your repo and that's probably causing the issue?

In my experience with CI I've always deployed entire code bases as packages to remove ambiguity.

Comment: No we have codebases that are 3-400mbs without assets and we regularly deploy. We don't want to push that out every time.